# How to selectively retrieve ELEMENTS using getElementsByTagName

Tags: java, xml, dom

I have a DOM XML - org.w3c.dom.Document

And I want to select only the first occurrence of PARENT within MAIN. Ie. Not retrieve the second PARENT element with Unwanted in.

So I'm using

```
NodeList nodeList = document.getElementsByTagName("PARENT");
```

Here is a sample of the XML.

```
<MAIN>
<PARENT>
     <CHILD>Billy</CHILD>
     <CHILD>Allen</CHILD>
</PARENT>
<PARENT>
     <CHILD>Unwanted</CHILD>
     <CHILD>Unwanted</CHILD>
</PARENT>
</MAIN>
```

However, the solution I've tried will retrieve all PARENT elements.

Is there a sweet way to select just the first PARENT element?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That seems like the best way.  What features would you expect a better solution to have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [`Document`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Document.html), you can only use `getElementsByTagName` and then retrieve the first with [`NodeList.item(0)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/NodeList.html#item%28int%29)

```
NodeList nodeList = document.getElementsByTagName("PARENT");
Node parent = nodeList.item(0);
```

or, if you know that `PARENT` is always the first child of the document node, you can retrieve `getDocumentElement()` and then retrieve the first child with [`getFirstChild()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Node.html#getFirstChild%28%29)

```
Element main = document.getDocumentElement();
Node parent = main.getFirstChild();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
document.getChileNodes().item(0);
```

OR

```
document.getFirstChild();
```